# How do I get rid of hanging wires in fallout 4

Tags: fallout-4

I have been upgrading Sanctuary in fallout 4 so I have made a working light system. With that I used wire, one of the wires glitched out and it is just hanging there and its getting in the way of my entrance so I was just wondering if there was any way to fix it?

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: When asking questions like this, you should mention whether you're on PC or console. Your options on the console version are somewhat restricted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it, you have to move left or right a bit from the wire and it will become highlighted

Comment: The highlighting in Workshop mode is definitely a little funky. Sometimes I can't get a bush or something to highlight so I can scrap it, then it highlights when I look off to the side at something else. Go figure.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found to remove glitched wires on is on the PC by selecting it via the console and typing in 'disable'.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into build mode, and select the wire you should be able to store it in your workshop.

This means that you'll be able to use it again next time you build wires.

Comment: I have already tried that nothing happens it's like it's not even meant to be there? Now that i think about it i should of put that in the question.

Comment: if it's indeed glitched, restarting the game might fix it. Or temporarilly storing the thing it connects to on the other end.

Comment: It's happened for a while so restarting wont work i may try storing the switch it's attached to.

Comment: @Dragon4c3_ You should definitely put that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest building something as close to it as possible (clipping if you can). Then while in the build menu long press E (or equivalent button on a console) to select all attached. Move it somewhere out of sight and then store/scrap your temporary item.